# How can a CD derive Track Information from another source (e.g. Amazon)?

Tags: windows-10

Windows Media Player (WMP) lacks, or has wrong details of, the Track Information for some CDs.

Instead of editing each title inefficiently, how can information from another source (like Amazon) be imposed on the CD, more efficiently?

Comment: So what attributes or meta data from these audio files is messed up exactly? What are you downloading these from and what protocol are you using to get the audio files from Amazon or whatever (e.g. HTTP, FTP, SMB, and so on)? Are you needing track information such as length or what? I would think you clarifying some of these aspects would potentially be helpful to people that may be able to help you get this resolved. Please clarify with more specificity and detail of what exactly you need to fix or get corrected with these files and it's metadata.

Answer (score 0):

If you like stick with WMP you can try to find updated metadata as described [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15693/update-metadata-and-cover-art-in-windows-media-player-12/).

If you have ripped your CDs to MP3/WMA I recommend to use [mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/) to do add the metadata automatically for you. There are other tools like this, but mp3tag is among the best and free.

Alternatively, you could use a different Media Player that uses a more regularly updated CD database, maybe VLC or iTunes.